# Code doesn't find string in txt file. Whats wrong with my code?

Tags: java, file-io, while-loop

I'm writing this code to look inside a txt file and find me a string that the user gave as input. My txt file contains the lines as such (this info will be important later):

first line - blank.
second line - idan
third line - yosi

now, if the user inputs "idan" as the user (without the "") the code will find it. If the user puts in "yosi" it wont find it. It's like my code is reading only the second line. I'm new in programming and this is just a practice for me to learn how to read and write to files, please be patient with me.

here is the code (there is a catch and also the else statement but they where left off for length reasons):

```
    //Search for the specific profile inside.
        try{        
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("d:\\profile.txt"));
            System.out.println("Searching for your Profile...");


            int linecount = 0;
            String line;
            while (br.readLine() !=null){
                linecount++;

                if(userName.contentEquals(br.readLine())){
                    System.out.println("Found, " + userName + " profile!");
                    break;
                }
                else{

                }
```

Comment: please post the top ~5 lines from your profile.txt as well

Comment: `userName.contentEquals(br.readLine())` You need to post the relevant code related to this line. Right now we don't have all the information about your code to give you useful input.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this:

```
*if(userName.contentEquals(br.readLine())){*
```

you are reading an additional line.  You will find it reads every other line with your implementation.  That is line 2,4,6,etc

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the following place:

```
if(userName.contentEquals(br.readLine()))
```

You don't need to read it again because you have already read it in the while loop:

```
while (br.readLine() !=null)
```

So, you basically read line1 (do nothing with it), then read line2 (do something with it) and the process starts over.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do something like
    ...
    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        ...
    }

Every call to `BufferedReader.readLine()` reads the next available line from the file. Since you read one line in the `while` statement and read the next line for the `if` statement, you're only checking the even numbered lines.

Comment: thanks for the reply's! I did what you and the others said and removed one "readLine" from the code but it still doesn't find the user input. here is the new code:

 int linecount = 0;
    String line;
    
    while ((line = br.readLine()) !=null){
   
     

     if(userName == line){
      System.out.println("Found, " + userName + " profile!");
     }
     else{
      System.out.println("couldnt find");
     }

Comment: I now read the BufferedReader api at Sun documentations and specifically the .readLine method, and it says:

"A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed."

could it be that my while loop cannot read the lines of text because they are not terminated with \n \r? (which they really dont).

Comment: Don't compare `String`s with `==`. Use `.equals()`.